# convergence of a sequence with sine product

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let$$P_n=\prod_{k=1}^n k\sin\frac{x}{k}$$ For which $x$ this sequence converges?

---

I have done trivial cases only:

For $x\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$ all $P_n$ are 0's.

For $x\in(-1,1)$ it converges to 0 by the use of $|\sin t|\le|t|$.

Comment: Your first trivial case is not true, and your second trivial case is not that trivial! 
$$ \begin{align} P_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}k\,\sin(x/k) &= x^n\,\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sin(x/k)}{(x/k)} \\ |x|\gt1 \quad &: \quad P_n\rightarrow\infty \\ x\in[0,+1[ \quad &: \quad P_n=0 \\ x=+1 \quad &: \quad P_n=c \\ x=-1 \quad &: \quad P_n\rightarrow\{+c,-c\} \\ x\in]-1,0[ \quad &: \quad P_n\rightarrow\,\color{red}{?} \end{align} $$

Comment: @HazemOrabi The first case is trivially true. You've also written a bunch of things that are not correct, such as $P_n=0,P_n = c.$ Also, you've given no reasons.

Comment: $$ \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}k\,\sin(\pi/k)=0\times\infty $$

Comment: @HazemOrabi Therefore the first factor is $0$ in all the $P_n.$ So all $P_n = 0$!

Comment: For a chosen $\,n\,$, yes $\,P_n=0\,$. But for $\,n\to\infty\,$, the story is different. [Check Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5Bk+Sin%5BPi%2Fk%5D,+%7Bk,+1,+Infinity%7D%5D).

Comment: @HazemOrabi This is getting silly. If $x\in \pi \mathbb Z,$ then all $P_n=0.$

Comment: @zhw.: With all respect, for $\,n\to\infty\,$, it is an indefinite case of $\,0\times\infty\,$ which require a limit treatment to remove the indefinite. That is my opinion, and maybe I am wrong. Apologizing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for $x=1.$ We can write

$$P_n= \exp \left (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln (k\sin (1/k)) \right).$$

Thus $P_n$ converges if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ln (k\sin (1/k))$converges. Use $\sin u = u + O(u^3)$ and $|\ln(1+u)| \le 2|u|$ for $|u|$ small to see this sum does indeed converge.

Comment: Where did $x$ go?

Comment: @martycohen $x=1.$

Comment: For $x=1$, indeed $P_n$ converges. (+1)